# Neo4j: how to sum an array element with the previous one?

Tags: arrays, xcode, function, neo4j, cypher

I am using Cypher with Neo4j and I need to sum each array elements with the sum between previous elements.

With the following example:

```
[1,2,3,4,5]
```

I would the following result:

```
[1,3,6,10,15]
```

I am trying in this way:

```
[i in range(0,size(array)-1) | array[i]+array[i-1]]
```

But it doesn't work.
Any advice for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query is calculating sum only two elements(current and previous elements) from the original array.

What you need is the sum of all the previous elements, for that you need to first get the list of all the previous elements including the current one and then sum all.

To calculate the sum of all elements you can use [reduce function](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/functions/list/#functions-reduce).

You can modify your query as follows:

```
WITH [1,2,3,4,5] as array
WITH [i IN range(0,size(array)-1) | reduce(total=0, num IN array[0..i+1] | total + num) ] AS new_array
RETURN new_array
```

Comment: I tried but i have this error:   
Neo.ClientError.Statement.SyntaxError: Invalid input ' ': expected whitespace, '.', node labels, '[', "=~", IN, STARTS, ENDS, CONTAINS, IS, '^', '*', '/', '%', '+', '-', '=', '~', "<>", "!=", '<', '>', "<=", ">=", AND, XOR, OR, WHERE, '|', ']' or ',' (line 4, column 34 (offset: 290))
"WITH [i IN range(0,size(array)-1) | reduce(total=0, num IN array[0..i+1] | total + num) ] as new_array"